# Error 1067 when trying to start my newly created service

Tags: c++, mysql, service, mysql++

I've been busy writing a login server for a larger server network I'm developing (game servers) and I've hit a problem.

So I'm creating a login service using RakNet and MySQL. RakNet is fine and it works great but now I want to attach a database so I can keep registered users and let them log in. Now, I added all include and lib things to my project properties and I use mysql++ to connect to my database.

Everything compiles fine and I get no errors but when I try to start the service, after installing it correctly, I get an error 1067 that it can't be started.

I have this error since I've implemented mysqlpp but I have no idea how to solve it (been searching the internet for days). I tried reinstalling the MySQL server but that didn't help. I have the latest version of mysql++ by the way.

Anyone knows how to solve or debug this problem? Thanks in advance!

Comment: OS? Error logs? Does it run interactively? Can you attach a debugger?

Comment: Windows 7 x64. No I guess it doesn't. It won't even start so no, I can't attach a debugger (normally I attach visual studio 2012 after starting the service)

Comment: You should be able to *start it* in a debugger regardless. When working on services I typically separate the service control code and the app so I can debug interactively.

Comment: Sounds great! I guess it's something like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255335/how-to-runf5-windows-service-from-visual-studio) then?

Comment: Ok, so to add to this (also noticed the link is for c#), I will try and work out how to add this service control code to my service and try and debug interactively with it. Thanks a lot!